# Postgresql trigger function that queries data from a second table with possible race condition

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I need to produce a trigger function that will fire, probably after update on one table that uses the data returned by that row insert to query data from a second table and return that data to the user.

Putting the function together should be OK I think, but, there is the possibility that the second table may not have the required data yet (I can't be sure the second table will be updated before this trigger fires).

Is there a way I can capture the fact that the return is null and put in a wait to try again a short time later?

Not getting any sense as to how I can do this from my searching.

OK, more contexts as requested. The tables are being loaded by an external process which reads csv files and imports the data into the database. The order of loading is not consistent so I can't (I don't think) rely on the second table being loaded when the trigger on the target tables fires.

Comment: Can you give a higher-level description of what you are trying to do? In particular, _why_ the second table may not already have the necessary update.

Comment: More context in the answer now, sorry for not making it clearer.